# Is there a reason for support multiple different releases?

Tags: design, deployment, configuration-management

I have a discussion with my team recently and I heard a suggestion for deploying multiple releases. Such as `version (newest)` and `version (old)`.
But I am thinking what would be the reason for customer want to use the older version. What if the bug was introduced in the older version we would have to make additional support to it.

I see there are benefits of using older version. Maybe I am wrong but what would be the reason why people want the older releases?? and if the trade off wasnt worth it (support vs demand) then why are we plan to support multiple releases?

Comment: Stability of interface, risk avoidance.

Comment: [What is the standard /an acceptable period of time to support a particular version of software?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/109432/what-is-the-standard-an-acceptable-period-of-time-to-support-a-particular-versi)

Comment: Is every single piece of software on your computer 100% up-to-date with the most cutting-edge version? Are you sure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Older versions can bring stability to a software deployment.

New versions of software may introduce new bugs, potentially crippling bugs. For anything mission-critical, only battle-tested software should be deployed in order to reduce risk. If you want the latest and greatest then put it on a desktop or other non-critical system.

This is the thought process behind [Ubuntu's LTS (long-term support)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) strategy. You can update to regular releases if you want, but there are periodic stable releases. Every few versions focus on stability and are supported for longer with fewer major changes introduced over their life. The idea is to provide a stable release for mission-critical systems (e.g. servers) where "changing random things" can break stuff. These LTS releases typically only receive security and bug fixes, with new features being reserved for the standard release cycle.

Other vendors follow similar configuration management practices as well, supporting older versions with security patches. Once a newer version has proven to be stable in the wild, a company may upgrade their critical systems to it.

**TL;DR: stability and the lack of nasty surpises.**

Answer (score 5):

There can be several reasons to stay with an older release:

- New releases may cost money for a new license. If the older release is sufficient, why spend the money?
- New releases may cost money and/or time (a.k.a. money) to learn and/or install. Again, why bother if the older release works?
- New releases may break things. This may be intentional (removing deprecated behaviors that some people weren't quite done using), or it may be a bug. Either way, the new version doesn't work, but the old does.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons a customer may be reticent to push on to the latest software version. Some reasons I've come across:

**Known quantity**

The customer may simply be very happy with a legacy version. They know all the foibles, how to fix things should they go wrong and how to get the very best out of the software.

**Time**

The customer may not have time to install/learn the new software. There may also need to be a time window for new software to be installed which in turn may require authorisation.

**Test lag**

Larger companies can insist that new software is put thru its paces by a test dept before general release. There may be a time lag while this arranged and processed.

**3rd party software**

3rd party software may only integrate with older versions of your software until such time as they've played catch up.

**No desirable features**

You may think new features X, Y & Z are the best thing since sliced bread, but if your customer doesn't see their value - why should they upgrade?

**Interface**

Even the best software companies are known to drop the ball occasionally with endless interface tinkering e.g. Microsoft's Office ribbon. Wholesale changes to the software interface can be hugely unpopular.

**Technical assets**

If your software generates assets such as XML files, data in databases and various log files, these may be of value to the customer outside the sphere of your software. In a previous job we used bug tracking software that dumped log files whenever it went over. The vendor was based in the USA so we sometimes had a 2 day turnaround for them to look the logs over and resolve the issue. Trawling thru the log files ourselves often allowed us to cast light on the issue. A proposed upgrade to the software hid these away so we stuck with the old version.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use Windows 7, while Microsoft released newer versions meanwhile? Similarly, one can decide to keep an older version of Linux, or an older version of Python.

Some factors one should take in account :

- The price of the new version.
- The operations cost of upgrading.
- The time needed to learn the new version.
- Backwards compatibility: if you have built an app for Python 2, you don't necessarily want to spend the next two months adapting it for Python 3.
- Dependencies: the next OS doesn't necessarily support a library you use.
- New bugs: what if the new version introduces new bugs the old version doesn't have?
- And most importantly, what if you just don't need the new version because the previous one responds to all your needs?